# Ruby on Rails , Gem Devise Customization

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Hi i am currently working on my Ruby on Rails project and i wanted to customize the devise gem but my problem is that i cant seem to find some tutorials on how to customize devise more specifically customizing the login, parameters.

I already customized the login and the view of the device , but my problem is it doesn't seem to create the username , firstname , lastnamge , age , etc.

and it only gets the email and password etc. the basic stuff

i know the documentation is great and all specially because it is complete but my problem is that i find it a bit hard to follow specially when i cant see the video or how can i customize what i can put inside in the devise if anybody can help me with this , or any information on some tutorials with actually doing what i specified above that would be great and will really be appreciated , and please i am a bit new on RoR so i find it a bit difficult in just reading the text so i need some vdeo and thanks!

```
simplybel@simplybel:~/projects/gamification$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.6)
2.1.2 :001 > User.all
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 7, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, profile_name: nil, email: "pat@yahoo.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$xg.HMU2JljnVLls3IX7Go.IfJVLGYSSRePjtDaYS4nE...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2014-12-01 23:50:17", last_sign_in_at: "2014-12-01 23:50:17", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2014-12-01 23:50:17", updated_at: "2014-12-01 23:50:17">]>
```

2.1.2 :002 >

this is the what the rails console returned after taking your advice, here is the code that you can clone

```
https://github.com/sanchez900/gamification.git
```

that is the code before I did the changes like the

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
end
end
```

i also did this

```
rails generate devise:views
```

also did the controllers
    rails generate devise:controllers users

did the routes
    devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions" }

some other info might help also the project clone / link is before i did the modifications

Comment: check my updated answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

If you had setup your view correctly to submit all the addition parameters, then you need to do as instructed in the docs https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters.

You need to update your permitted parameters on your sign up form to accept the new parameters you need. To do this, you can set a before filter to configure the permitted params for your devise controllers.  Try something like this in your application controller.

```
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :profile_name) }
    end
```

### you need to explicitly write it as above (or use .push if you prefer)

---

Comment: Hi i tried the code and this is what it showed me ill update the details

Comment: Hi thanks for the help finnaly figured out why misplaced it in the wrong file and now working really thanks needed the sleep havent slept for like 2 day slept just yesterday and bam! it worked thanks again!